# Android: Java: The Deprecation of SlidingDrawer

Tags: java, android, menu, navigation, drawer

After doing some reading on developer.android.com I am seriously considering the removal of menu drawer navigation from my app.

Before I do, however, I wanted to hear your opinion: why was `android.widget.SlidingDrawer` deprecated as of API 17?

**EDIT:**

This is a valid question. Why the `android.widget.SlidingDrawer` got deprecated? and what else can be used in place of Sliding drawer to get same effect?

Comment: I feel this is valid question, just because author mentioned "**I wanted to hear your opinion**" does not make the question "not constructive". I would also like to know, what could be the reason, it got deprecated.

Comment: I think such widgets can be implemented using Fragments and FragmentTransactions so when there is always more than one way to do something it makes sense to simplify the API by deprecating (and at a later date) removing functionality.

Comment: Please re-open this question. I would like to know peoples' opinions to this perfectly valid question. I think it was way OTT to close it.

Comment: Someone told me that SlidingDrawer didn't do the same thing as the 3rd-party SlidingMenu that has become so popular.

Comment: Please reopen this question